# document.activeElement not working on canvas element

Tags: javascript, html

I got a WebGL canvas rendered from an emscripten port. I'm trying to create a ghetto pause screen for it, but for some reason I can not get document.activeElement to detect the canvas. From everything I've read, it should be working.

```
var testCanvas = document.getElementById("canvas")

function testFocus() {
if (document.activeElement === testCanvas[0]) {
console.log('canvas has focus');
} else {
console.log('canvas not focused');
}};
window.setInterval(testFocus, 1000);
```

[JSFiddle replicating the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/42x34k68/3/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have two errors in your code

1st it's `tabindex` not *tab-index*

2nd it's `if (document.activeElement === testCanvas) // not testCanvas[0]`

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="578" height="480" tabindex="1">  
</canvas>

var testCanvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
var testSpan = document.getElementById("plswork")
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var imageObj = new Image();

imageObj.onload = function() {
  context.drawImage(imageObj, 69, 50);
};
imageObj.src = 'https://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg';

function testFocus() {
  if (document.activeElement === testCanvas) {
    console.log('canvas has focus');
  } else {
    console.log('canvas not focused');
  }
};
window.setInterval(testFocus, 1000);
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/42x34k68/6/

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm too embarrassed to say how long I've been at this. Answer accepted.